# Is there a list of Visual Studio warning definitions?

Tags: visual-studio, warnings

At the moment I'm interested in source code analysis and playing around with the built-in possibilities and other third party plguins.
The biggest problem for me, is to identify or filter for code analysis related warnings in the error list window of Visual Studio.

I think all warnings starting with "CA" are these types of errors. Anyway I'm still not sure and want to get this clarified, so that I have knowledge about this and not just a feeling/believe.

This problem brings me in general to the question: Is there a list of all error/warning "groups" and what they are related to? Is it possible that there are "custom" defined "groups"?
I think this is important since every warning will be pushed to the same window. Based on the task someone is working on, it can be pretty hard to identify relvant warnings/outputs (especially in huge projects).

So far my results or what I think is the meaning (list may be uncomplete):

- CA - Source Code Analysis, based on this [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1hzekz.aspx)
- CS - C# compiler in general, based on assumption (I get these while compiling C#)
- AD - ?? (I get these from "Roslyn Security Guard" when throwing exceptions while analysing code)
- C - C/C++ compiler in general, based on assumption (I know this group of warnings from C/C++ projects)
- SG - ?? (Maybe these are warnings coming from successfull analysed code with Roslyn Security Guard (SG = Security Guard?))

Answer (score 1):

Yes SG comes from Roslyn Security Guard. It is a custom name chosen by developer of the analyzer. This is why there is no single list of warnings. Only groups of warnings produced by Microsoft are documented on Msdn. AD001 is shown when an analyzer itself throws an exception because of a bug in it.